# Determing an iframe's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

On my page, I have an iframe tag that I control.  The iframe src attribute points to another page on my domain.  Inside this iframe is a Javascript < script > tag that will call code to serve an ad of some sort.  The ad is either 300px (w) x 250px  (h) or 500px (w) x 500px (h), but I don't know which ad will be served.  The ad Javascript has no callback function that I can use to obtain height and width information.

So, this tag is on my page.

```
<iframe src="http://mydomain.com/page_that_has_ad_code_that_will_run.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Is there a cross-browser way to determine the height of the iframe after the inside Javascript finishes running?  Native Javascript or jQuery is fine.  Thank you.

I have tried $('iframe').contents().height(); but I'm not sure that is the proper way.  (It currently returns a value greater than 250 or 500, so it's probably picking up all the immediate children tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an element of an iframe with the follow code:
first you should give your iframe a name, and your ad an id

```
parent.frames['name_of_iFrame'].document.getElementById('id_of_element').height;
```

and you should do the same for the width